# Cannot Convert List[Any] to List[(String,String)]

Tags: scala

I have a Scala List

```
freq_items_list
List[Any] = List(Array((fid,1007)), Array((tes,d0920)), Array((tn,r3026), (fd,1007)), Array((tn,g5260_p2)), Array((testN
ame,g5260_p2), (fd,1007)), Array((tn,c7835)), Array((tn,g5250_p2)), Array((tn,g5250_p2), (fd,1007)), Array((tn,r7090)),
Array((tn,r7090), (fd,1007)))
```

I try converting it to List[(String,String)] by using

```
frequent_items_list.map(_.asInstanceOf[Array[(String, String)]])
```

However when I try that I get a ClassCastException

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lscala.Tuple2;
```

I am new to Scala is there another way to convert this and what is wrong with the current way?

Comment: Your code looks incomplete. It is better if we see the types of your variables etc. Should you share the whole code, it would be easier to debug it.

Comment: Casting from one type to another is almost always wrong. It opens you up to runtime exceptions (as you've seen). You're basically telling the compiler, "Take away your safety protections. I know what I'm doing. (Or at least I think so.)"

Comment: And right after the runtime says: "Ops, no, you didn't know what you were doing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you a `List[(String, String)]` result even if the tuple elements are not strings (they can even be a mix of types), but it will drop any `List` element that is not an `Array()` and it will drop any `Array` elements that aren't 2-tuples.

```
freq_items_list.flatMap{case a:Array[_]=> a.toList; case _ => List()}
               .collect{case (x,y) => (x.toString, y.toString)}
```

Comment: Some arrays in question have more than one element: `Array((testN
ame,g5260_p2), (fd,1007))`, for example.

Comment: @P.Frolov; Good catch. I had tested with a reduced data set. Fixed.